# How can I implement li:last-child with less?

Tags: css, less

I have the following CSS:

```
ul.arbo {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    }
ul.arbo li {color
    padding-bottom: 0.333em;
    }
ul.arbo li:last-child {
      color: #333;
    }
```

I can implement the simple CSS using Less. But how do I implement the li:last-child?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
ul.arbo {
    margin-top: 0.5em;

    li {
        color: #444;
        padding-bottom: 0.333em;

        &:last-child {
         color: #333;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From [docs](http://lesscss.org/#-nested-rules): Notice the & combinator—it’s used when you want a nested selector to be concatenated to its parent selector, instead of acting as a descendant.